# Using object id as a hash for objects in Python

Tags: python, hash

Is it wise to use the object `id` as a hash key (via. the `__hash__`) to be able to hash an otherwise mutable object for a single instance of a program? Using the object attributes would be nicer but they're all mutable and can change.

This occurred to me while looking at [Sets of instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038010/sets-of-instances/2038019) and I'm wondering if it's wise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, as long as you also define `__eq__` (and presumably `__ne__`!-) consistently with that. IOW, it's fine, as long as you're fine with `a==b` meaning exactly the same as `a is b`!-)

Comment: Thanks. Your second sentence clarifies it quite well.

Answer (score 7):

For most Python classes this is the default behaviour. The unhashable ones are unhashable for a good reason: they are mutable collections.

For collections it is practical to have the equality relation (as defined by `__eq__()`) based on equality of their contents. This, and the requirement for `__hash__()` to be consisent with equality, would of course make the `__hash__()` mutable, which would be horrible for collections containing such objects.

So you can do this but it costs you the content-based equality relation.