# How to make a hashable and comparable custom object with mutable fields in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, hash

I want to define a hashable class with mutable fields, but if I define the `__eq__` method myself (which definitely I want to do), it is no longer hashable by default and I need to define `__hash__` method as well.

If I define the `__hash__` method such that it just compares the `id()` values like it (I think) did by default before I defined `__eq__` I get weird results.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040101/using-object-id-as-a-hash-for-objects-in-python), I have to define `__eq__` the same way as `__hash__` but I would like to understand why this is the case and, if possible, how to work around that.

To be specific, I want to define objects with two mutable fields containing integers:

```
class CustomObj:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

ObjA = CustomObj(1, 2)
ObjB = CustomObj(1, 2)
```

I want to be able to compare them to each other `ObjA == ObjB`, as well as to simple tuples `ObjA == (1, 2)`. I also want to be able to store them in a set `myset = set()`, so that I can check both `(1, 2) in myset` and `ObjA in myset` for the same result. How can I achieve this?

This is my code at the moment, but it's definitely not behaving correctly:

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            # Try comparing two agents
            return (self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
                        and isinstance(other, Agent))
        except AttributeError:
            # If it fails, compare an agent and a tuple
            if isinstance(other, tuple) and len(other) == 2:
                return self.x == other[0] and self.y == other[1]
            else:
                return NotImplemented

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)
```