# Get list of unique objects with no unique attributes from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with a list of objects as values like:

```
{"A": [obj1, obj2, obj3], "B": [obj1, obj4, obj5]}
```

Here, I'd like to get a list of unique objects such as

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]
```

These objects **do not** have as single unique attribute (for ex. a unique id).

I tried using set() but since the objects aren't hashable I haven't had success.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
You have two steps: gather all of the dict values, and de-duplicate that list.  Each step is documented quite well; use your browser search.

Comment: are the objects hashable?

Comment: They aren't @James. Added appropriate edit.

Comment: @Prune Updated the question with some more info.

Comment: Declare a master empty list.  Iterate over each list in the dict.  If the current object is not in the master list, add it.

Comment: First, you have to define what makes object equal. Then, the rest get easier

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dictionary is `m` you can use a `set` like this:

```py
s = set()
m = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4,5,6]}
for v in m.values():
    t_set = set(v)
    s.update(t_set)

s
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

I see you say your objects are not hashable. If they are objects you have created, you can override the `__hash__()` function and define your own way to make them hashable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain` to make an  iterator over all the values. Then a simple trick using `dict.fromkeys` instead of a set to retain order while only keeping unique values. (Keep in mind that the objects must be indexable/hashable) You will need to figure out how these objects are comparable in order to accomplish this task at all.

```
from itertools import chain

data = {"A": [obj1, obj2, obj3], "B": [obj1, obj4, obj5]}

output = list(dict.fromkeys(chain(*data.values())))
```

---

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]
```

Answer (score -1):

The following works.

```
def get_unique_objs(data):
    ret = []
    for obj_list in data.values():
        for obj in obj_list:
            if obj not in ret:
                ret.append(obj)
    return ret
```

This will return you a list where no two objects are equal according to the objects' [__eq__ magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) if available and/or a comparison with the `is` operator (which is implemented by the Python interpreter and is always available and [cannot be overriden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399024/does-the-is-operator-use-a-magic-method-in-python)).

In some circumstances there might be a little bit more coming into play as well. [This shows the complete process](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)  of checking if an object should be added to the resulting list.

Comment: You should replace `for obj_list in data` with `for obj_list in data.values()`

Comment: @zinngg I've fixed it.